# vertical menu/nav auto scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking for jquery plugin or something for my vertical menu. here is the scenario.. I have a long list of categories e.g. 70 categories, which I have to display in the right/left navigation, but I want them to display only 10 categories and soon as someone rolls over categories (up/down) it automatically scrolls up/down and shows remaining categories within the specific height (10 visible at a time), I hope my question is clear if not, I will demonstrate with images.. can someone please point me to the right direction.. thanks...

Edit: something like this but with only category names and in vertical direction : http://valums.com/files/2009/menu/final.htm

Comment: Visit the page you linked to, right-click, view source, copy the simple javascript code and modify to your needs

Answer (score 0):

As MrOBrian said...you can edit the style part in the source code. This also depends on target browsers. Here is something to get you started...

```
div.sc_menu {
/* Set it so we could calculate the offsetLeft */
position: relative;
height: 145px;
width: 200px;
overflow: auto;
    /* Added this part */
writing-mode: tb-lr;
filter: flipv fliph;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Added this part */
```

}

Comment: Thanks Vikram and Brian. I have found this, it may help someone looking for something similar : valums.com/files/2009/vertical-menu/final.htm